# c# implementing a timer

Tags: c#, timer

I was struggling with implementation of a `timer` more than i should so i have decided to post a question here.

This is my class:

```
public static class CurrentPoint
    {
        public static Single X { get; set; }
        public static Single Y { get; set; }
        public static Single Z { get; set; }
        public static long   ID { get; set; }

        public static float CalcVar { get; set; }
        public static float CalcStatic { get; set; }


        public static bool StartTimeOut()
        {

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I should have a method implemented in it `StartTimeOut()`. `StartTimeOut()` will be called from another class when some other method will execute.

In `StartTimeOut()` i should have a `timer` that would check if `CalcVar` will change in **next 30 seconds**.

Now if it will, i will receive a `TRUE` from my `StartTimeOut()` and `timer` should exit if not `StartTimeOut()` will return a `false`.

This check for `CalcVar` will be done under same `CurrentPoint.ID`. That means if `ID` changes durring timer checks timer should exit and `StartTimeOut()` would return a `TRUE`.

There should also be a check if timer is already running and again STOP timer if CalcVar reaches 0 under 30 seconds under same ID
and StartTimeOut() again returns TRUE.

I hope i haven't complicated this problem too much.

Comment: also look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer for a small tutorial on using Timers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small sample, do understand that whenever you call this function it will remain in the while loop as long as it is running. Perhaps you should call the StartTimeOut() function from inside another thread...

```
//do not forget
using System.Timers;

private Timer _timer;
private static long _id;
private static bool _returnValue;
private static int _achievedTime;

public static bool StartTimeOut()
{
  //set your known values (you need to check these values over time
  _id = ID;
  _achievedTime = 0;
  _returnValue = true;

  //start your timer
  Start();

  while(_timer.Enabled)
  {
    //an empty while loop that will run as long as the timer is enabled == running
  }
  //as soon as it stops
  return _returnValue;
}

//sets the timer values
private static void Start()
{
  _timer = new Times(100); //describes your interval for every 100ms
  _timer.Elapsed += HandleTimerElapsed;
  _timer.AutoReset = true; //will reset the timer whenever the Elapsed event is called

  //start your timer
  _timer.Enabled = true; //Could also be _timer.Start();
}

//handle your timer event
//Checks all your values
private static void HandleTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  _achievedTime += _timer.Interval;
  //the ID changed => return true and stop the timer
  if(ID!= _id)
  {
      _returnValue = true;
      _timer.enabled = false; //Could also be _timer.Stop();
  }
  if(CalcVar == 0) //calcVar value reached 0 => return false and stop the timer
  {
    _returnValue = false;
    _timer.Enabled = false;
  }
  if(_achievedTime = 30000) //your 30s passed, stop the timer
    _timer.Enabled = false;          
}
```

this is what you call simply code do not test!